# incompatible types: long cannot be converted to Instant

Tags: java, time, java-time, incompatibletypeerror, java.time.instant

I'm testing an example from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html). But getting this error `incompatible types: long cannot be converted to Instant` .

Code:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.Temporal;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;


class HelloWorld {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Instant previous = Instant.parse("2022-04-16T08:03:50.054341Z"), current, gap;
    
    
        current = Instant.now();
        if (previous != null) {
            gap = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(previous,current);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Hello, World! "+current+ " , "+previous + " , "+gap); 
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That's a bug in the tutorial alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
gap = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(previous,current);
```

calculates the number of milliseconds between two times.  Then it takes that number and tries to assign it to `gap`, which is of type `Instant`.  In other words, you're taking a number, and trying to assign it to something which can only store a moment in time.

You should have declared `gap` as a `long`, not an `Instant`.

Comment: seems like an error in the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html): "`Instant previous, current, gap;`"  :-/

Comment: Yes, it's an error in that tutorial.